# Draw multiline text on top of canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-bitmap

So I initially started with this code below:

```
private Bitmap writeTextOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text) {

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId);
    Bitmap alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
    paint.setTextSize(150f); 
    canvas.drawText(text, 100, 1000, paint); 

    return alteredBitmap;
}
```

It worked just as intended the background image was there and so was the text except the text was too long for the screen and I needed to wrap it somehow.

I then looked looked into `TextPaint` and `StaticLayout` to handle the multiline problem with this code.

```
private Bitmap writeTextOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text) {

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId);
    Bitmap alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);
    TextPaint tp = new TextPaint();
    canvas.save();
    tp.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    tp.setTextSize(150f);
    tp.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    tp.setAntiAlias(true);
    StaticLayout sl = new StaticLayout("" + text, tp,
            canvas.getWidth(), Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
    canvas.translate(100, 1000);
    sl.draw(canvas);

    return alteredBitmap;
}
```

This didn't work at all. My background image was now gone and it was displaying over nothing. The text wasn't centered were it was before. The only benefit was that the text was now on multiple lines.

Does anyone know why the text changed its initial starting point and why the background image to the canvas disappeared? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your text shifted from the initial starting point because of canvas.translate() function. I don't know why your background image disappeared, because you never mentioned where (how) the bitmap's used. If you want the text to appear at the left top corner of a view, here is an example.

Create ImageView (iv) and set its bitmap as:

```
iv.setImageBitmap(writeTextOnDrawable(drawableId, text));
```

Now your function:

```
private Bitmap writeTextOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text) {

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId);
    // Create your ImageView-size bitmap
    Bitmap alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(iv.getWidth(), iv.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);
    TextPaint tp = new TextPaint();
    tp.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    tp.setTextSize(24);
    tp.setAntiAlias(true);
    StaticLayout sl = new StaticLayout(text, tp,
        iv.getWidth(), Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
    sl.draw(canvas);

    return alteredBitmap;
}
```

After that you should see multiline text on your background image.

Comment: Correct. That's because in onCreate() your layout's views aren't layed out yet, so their widths and heights = 0. You should call iv.setImageBitmap(writeTextOnDrawable(drawableId, text)) only after the view has been layed out. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312350/android-how-to-tell-when-a-specific-view-has-been-rendered/22312916#22312916) where instead of button use imageView.

Comment: @Will Jamieson Apparently, since you get this error, your imageview width and height = 0 in onCreate(), no matter if you create it dynamically. I believe, any view is layed out at some point which is behind the onCreate() method. Till that point its dimension = 0 and a good approach to catch it when it's changed is to use ViewTreeObserver(). I actually never tried to set a certain value, say, to a view height and check if it's not 0 in onCreate. Even if it's so, I think this is not what you need.