# When do View dimensions become available to MainActivity?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, view, dimensions

Let's say we have a main_activity.xml layout that defines all dimensions in a relative manner -- constraints, percentages, and guidelines (that are percentages)... no "static" dp.

But in MainActivity.java, we programatically create some subviews, and we want to define their height/width dimensions as relative to existing views.

We do not know the dimensions or density of the device so, so nor do we know the (actual integer) dimensions of any view before run-time...

But we can say something like:

```
int heightDimensionForNewView = (int) (someAlreadyInflatedView.getHeight() / 7f)
```

*But what if, under certain circumstances, these "new" views need to be displayed immediately at app start-time?*

So, the question:

*In the Android Activity life-cycle, when is the earliest point at which you can (somehow) safely query (something) for actual/finalized/guaranteed layout dimensions?  And what is that something and somehow?*

I haven't been able to find an override method such as "onContentViewInflated()" and there is no onCreateView() method like there is in Fragments.

I've also tried Logging from inside onStart() and onResume() but the dimension results are always "0," presumably because they haven't been inflated yet.

I know that any given View can get its own dimensions in onMeasure(), but then you would have make a static variable in MainActivity in order to assign it and use it from there... or some way of sending that information from the View back to the Activity.

What am I missing?  I just want to be able to get the number somehow from inside MainActivity itself.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions are:

```
view.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        int oldWidth = oldRight - oldLeft; // right exclusive, left inclusive
        if( v.getWidth() != oldWidth ) {
            // width has changed
        }
    }
});
```

and

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // View has laid out

        // Remove the layout observer if you don't need it anymore
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: With `ViewTreeObserver` approach you have to remove `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to avoid multiple calls as I mentioned in [How to tell when a specific view has been rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22312916/3290339)