# ViewTreeObserver is running permanently

Tags: java, android

At a sertain point I implemented a vto on my scrollView to scroll to a certain point. This piece of Code is part of a method:

```
`if (timeCalc >= 230 && timeCalc < 240) {
                ViewTreeObserver vto = scrollView.getViewTreeObserver();
                vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        scrollView.scrollTo(0, 27600);
                    }
                });

            }`
```

The problem is, that the onGlobalLayout method is activated at sertain times but the method it is in, not at all. So how does that vto work and how i can solve my problem.

Comment: _"ViewTreeObserver is running permanently"_ This is because you never remove the listener. You should remove it. An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22312916/3290339).